# Java - Make src/main/java compile with java 1.4 and src/test/java compile with 1.5

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, compiler-version

I have a project which must be compiled only with java 1.4. But I am planning to write some unit tests using mockito. I want a way to specify in pom so that `src/main/java` compiles with `jdk 1.4` but `src/test/java` compiles with `jdk 1.5`.

Is there a way to do this? If yes, what pom changes should be made?

Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rather strange set up. JDK 1.4 is ancient so I recommend you move to Java 6 if you can.

To answer your question you can use the [testTarget](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html#testTarget) parameter.

Example setup:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                    <testTarget>1.6</testTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```